# Prove if the set of triangles X is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, triangles, rational-numbers

So this question completely stumped me.

Let X be the set of all triangles ABC in the plane R^2 so that both coordinates of each points A, B, and C are rational numbers. Prove that the set X is countable?

I think it's countable but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There are only countably many elements of $\mathbb Q^6$.

Comment: Cantor's diagonal argument

Comment: @Divide1918: That is irrelevant.